# Using `qlot` from a Lisp REPL

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, quicklisp

I'm interested in using the [`qlot`](https://github.com/fukamachi/qlot) library from inside of a Lisp image to manage multiple local instances of `quicklisp`.

There doesn't seem to be any documentation on how to use it, except through a non-Lisp CLI interface, and the obvious

```
(qlot:with-local-quicklisp (#P"/a/path/here/") (qlot:install :skippy))
```

or

```
(qlot:with-local-quicklisp (#P"/a/path/here/") (qlot:quickload :skippy))
```

give me

```
Component "skippy" not found
   [Condition of type ASDF/FIND-SYSTEM:MISSING-COMPONENT]
```

What I'm looking for is a way to install a particular library by name. Basically, exactly how one would use `ql:quickload`, but targeting a specific, local directory instead of `~/quicklisp`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the intent is to modify dynamically scoped variables in a way that makes using `ql:quickload` directly possible.

So

```
(qlot:with-local-quicklisp (#P"/a/path/to/some/quicklisp/")
  (qlot/util:with-package-functions :ql (quickload)
    (quickload :skippy)))
```

will result in `skippy` being installed in the `quicklisp` instance at `#P"/a/path/to/some/quicklisp/"` instead of the default location.

This leaves me a bit perplexed as to what `qlot:quickload` is for; its `describe` output doesn't shed additional light.